# Binomial Distribution Confidence Interval

Tags: probability, statistics

Normally when I see confidence intervals it is in attempt to estimate a population parameter (probably poor wording). What I am trying to do is form a confidence interval for some theoretical values, and see if a simulation is behaving properly. For a simple example, consider a dice rolled $3333$ times. I am trying to construct a confidence interval $(90\%, 95\%, 99\%, 99.9\%)$ for the number of times a $6$ is rolled. I know the standard deviation is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, but am not sure how to use that to get a confidence interval. Also, is there a name for what I am trying do to. It doesn't seem like I am hypothesis testing. Thanks!

Comment: Look [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Confidence_intervals)

Comment: The name for what you are trying to do is constructing confidence interval for binomial distribution.

Comment: You may have your interpretation backwards. A confidence interval is not a function of a distribution, it is a function of a sample. This confuses students a lot, because we think of the confidence interval as some interval where we are "confident" that the population mean lies, but actually, it either lies in our *particular* interval or it doesn't. Probability only comes in when we think about generating many confidence intervals, and checking the fraction of the time that these intervals overlap the population mean.

Comment: Caveat:  the above is relative to the frequentist interpretation. Bayesians think about these things in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approximate confidence interval for a proportion. In general it is used for normally distributed variables. But you have 3333 identical and independent distributed (iid) random variables. So you can apply the *[central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)*.

The two sided limits are

$\Large{\left[\hat p-z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat p\cdot (1-\hat p)}{n}}, \  \hat p+z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\hat p\cdot (1-\hat p)}{n}}\right]}$

You have a sample size of $n=3333$. For a confidence level fo 90% the significance level is $\alpha=1-0.9=0.1$. Therefore  $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}=0.95$

To find $z_{0.95}$ you have to find the value of z, where the value of the standard normal distribution is 0.95. If you look at [this table](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf), you will find that $z_{0.95}\approx 1.645$

Comment: Thank you. Any reason the sample size n is 3000? I thought it would be 3333. Or is some sort of floor/rounding function to be used?

Comment: It was just a typo. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a square root sign over the term you are adding and subtracting from the probability? The way they are doing this at my work, is they are using the Excel function "confidence". We have an event with a theoretical probability of success of 1/30,263. They are calling the standard deviation p*(1-p). This isn't accounting for n, but they might account for that later in the calculation. They then use the Excel "confidence" function, with the probability and standard deviation, along with the sample size. This gives me something different than I got with your formula.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it. Something wrong with me today, sorry. Maybe you have now the same (more or less) result.

Comment: And $\hat p$ is not 1/6. $\hat p$ is the result of your sample. If you have 550 sixes in your sample, then $\hat p=\frac{550}{3333}$. Thus you have to proof, if 1/6 is in the confidence interval.